# How to make FreeBSD variant of cal start weeks on mondays?

Tags: freebsd, cal

Can week start day be changed in `cal` output?
Is it hardcoded? Notice: not the `ncal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For util-linux**

`man cal`:

> -m, --monday
>  Display Monday as the first day of the week.

**For FreeBSD**
According to this [recent thread on the FreeBSD boards](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=30945), you will need the [deskutils port](http://www.freshports.org/deskutils/cal).

**For Ubuntu**
There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bsdmainutils/+bug/908233): seems you can either use `ncal` or the debian patch.

Comment: We have different versions. Line from FreeBSD manual: `-m month Display the specified month.`

Comment: Works fine here... `util-linux 2.22-6` You might have specified BSD

Comment: Didn't know there are multiple variants. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, actually, but cal is provided by bsdmainutils 8.2.3. And `dpkg -L util-linux | grep cal` gives nothing.

Answer (score 1):

When `cal -m` does not work, you can try to alias `ncal -M -C` as `cal`. Works for me, but I am not sure that it will work in every variant of `cal` (and `ncal`).